# Create new list if

Tags: python, list

Say that I have a while loop that runs 'n' times. And I would like to create a new table every time 'n' is divisble by 7. Now I don't know what 'n' is so how can I make the program create a list and call it some random name like list1, list2, list3.. etc...
I've been wondering about this for a long time. Thanks.

Edit: Say 'n' is 1234 or 999900000. Hope you understand what I mean. 'n' is unknown.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a list to contain your new lists?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but you should **not** create dynamic variable names.  A better option is to store the names as keys in a dict and the "created table" as the corresponding value

```
n = 50
myd = {}
list_num = 1
for i in range(1, n):
    if i % 7 == 0:
        myd['list{}'.format(list_num)] = 'i = {}'.format(i)
        list_num += 1

print(myd)
```

Now all you have to do is replace `'i = {}'.format(i)` with a call to your method that creates your table(s)!

And to access a specific table you simply reference `myd['list#']`

(e.g. `'list1'`, `'list2'`, et cetera),

where `list1` is the first match to `if i % 7 == 0:`, which in your case is `7`,

and `list2` would be the second match (i.e. `14`).

Answer (score 0):

```
def yourFunction(n):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        if n % 7 == 0:
            create_new_table()  # or whatever your new table code is
```

Although I don't know what you mean by creating list1, list2, list3, etc. Perhaps you want to create a list that itself contains lists? Or create a dictionary with keys such as "list1", "list2", etc. and values of lists?

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what you mean with the list1, list2, list3 part, but I guess this gives an idea of how to solve this: modulo is your friend.

```
>>> n = 53;
>>> for i in range(0, n):
...   if i % 7 == 0:
...     list.append(i)
... 
>>> list
[0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49]
```